# How can I cut each line in a file when it reaches a space or comma in bash?

Tags: awk

I basically want the first word of each sentence in a file, but since words can be followed by punctuation, cutting after a space doesn't do it.

How can I have the first words in each sentence without punctuation?

For example, a list could be:

```
Hello, how are you?
Bla bla bla
```

Output:

```
Hello
Bla
```

Comment: Please do post samples of your input and expected output in your post. Also please do add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

With `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/(^[a-zA-Z]+).*/\1/' Input_file
```

With `awk`:

```
awk 'match($0,/^[a-zA-Z]+/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

---

---

In case we need to get till `()-` all characters from starting try:

```
awk 'match($0,/^[a-zA-Z]+\(\)-/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

To get everything till first non characters including `()-` try:

```
awk 'match($0,/^[[:alpha:]()-]+/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample input, (GNU) grep should suffice. E.g:

```
grep -Eo '^[[:alpha:]]+' file
```

Comment: How can one modify this to also include parentheses, hyphens, etc?

Comment: @S.D By adding them to bracket expression. Like `[[:alpha:]()-]`, hyphen must be at the end

Answer (score 0):

Remove everything after the first non-alphanumeric character and print:

```sh
awk 'gsub(/[^a-zA-Z0-9].*/, "")1' file
```

With POSIX character classes:

```sh
awk 'sub(/[^[:alnum:]].*/, "")1' file
```